# What's the difference between a [cstring], a [c-string], [c-strings] and a const char*?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Simple, the first three are 0-terminated strings common in C (and C++), as well as in designs inspired by them, the last might point to one (in either language).

Still, for some absurd reason they are different tags.

Who is the hero who synonymizes [c-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-string) and [c-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-strings) to [cstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cstring)?

For bonus points, enhance the tag-wiki, it's quite basic yet.

Comment: I didn't think it was even possible to have separate "cstring" and "c-string" tags... but we apparently do. :/

Comment: No, there's also the 2 I quoted, 1 of which isn't in the OP here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-string vs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cstring

Comment: @Wooble: Ok, somehow that one eluded me. Situation is even worse than I thought... Edited it in.

Comment: Note, the [cstring] tag has been used not only for C-style strings, but also for the Microsoft MFC C++ `CString` class.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: Does that mean we need an [mfc-cstring] tag, those should be changed to [mfc]+[string], or what?

Comment: Great nickname to ask this question!

Comment: `CString` is a class that wraps a null-terminted `char*` and stuffs some reference counting stuff before the start of the buffer: it is a `char*` pointing at the first byte of the string so if you pass it to `printf` or the like it 'just works'.  A `c-string` is a null terminated buffer of `char` data.  `c-strings` are multiple such buffers.

Comment: @Yakk: Andrew [already commented on the existence of MFC](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271390/whats-the-difference-between-a-cstring-a-c-string-c-strings-and-a-const?noredirect=1#comment94296_271390). Does not change that our [tag:cstring] is for c-style strings, not for that old MFC-class (which is far less used). Use [mfc] for mfc stuff.

Comment: I don't have any feelings one way or the other as to how the MFC use should be tagged. Also, apparently Swift has yet another `CString` type.

Answer (score 3):

Right now, [there is a synonym proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c-strings/synonyms) only needing one more vote for the last piece of this, [c-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-string) → [c-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-strings), and then there will be only one tag in use! [Vote for it!](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c-strings/synonyms)

Answer (score -5):

I think [c-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-string) simply refers to an array of characters ending with a null termination. This term is sometimes used from a C++ programmer's point of view, to keep it separate from std::string. And std::string has a method called `c_str()`, which converts a C++ string to a "C string".

The C library header string.h is also included in C++ through `#include <cstring>`, which refers to a different library than `#include <string>`.

There is apparently a non-standard wrapper class in Visual Studio called [`CString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174288.aspx). It is possible that [cstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cstring) was supposed to refer to this class.

---

- Is the tag [c-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-string) useful? I doubt it, the only place where it makes sense is in a C++ discussion about character arrays. From a C programmer's point-of-view, the tag doesn't make any sense, character arrays are just *strings* to them. Still, the tag seems to be used as much for C++ questions as for C questions. It seems that the C programmers tend to use it as some sloppy way of merging [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) together. So I think this tag could be safely deleted and nobody would miss it.
- Is the tag [c-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-strings) useful? No, this seems to merely be the plural form of the above. This tag makes most sense to burninate, although it is for some reason more frequently used than the singular version of the tag.
- Is the tag [cstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cstring) useful? Yes it is, but only if it refers to the Visual Studio class with the same name. The Wiki for this tag needs to be rewritten in that case.

Comment: I would argue that, following predominant use, [cstring] should stay the c-style (aka 0-terminated) string (Outside mfc-land, that's the only viable meaning of [cstring], especially if we leave C++ too, see eg. swift). Yes, the mfc-class is named `CString`, tough luck that, just retag to [mfc]+[string] or [mfcstring]. ([string] is a catch-all tag for all kinds of strings, counted, sentinel, rope, whatever. Arguably it might be too wide)