# Synonym requests for [c-string]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I have noticed that [c-string] has 3 similar tags.

- [cstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cstring) tag has 537 questions tagged with it.
- [c-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-string) tag has 46 questions tagged with it.
- [c-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-strings) tag has 308 questions tagged with it.

I think that [c-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-strings) should be made a synonym of [c-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-string). What should be done with [cstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cstring)? Currently, it refers to a c-string, the `cstring` header used in C++ and also the `string.h` header used in the C programming language. Also, a part [tag info of the tag [cstring]](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/cstring/info) should be added to the tag info of the [c-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-string) tag.

---

Another tag also requires to be made a synonym of the other.

- [kr-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kr-c) tag has 33 questions tagged with it.
- [kernighan-and-ritchie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kernighan-and-ritchie) tag has 148 questions tagged with it.

I think that [kr-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kr-c) should be made a synonym of [kernighan-and-ritchie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kernighan-and-ritchie).

I do not have a total of 5 score in any of the mentioned tags. So can anyone synonmize these tags?

Comment: kr-c is the language (pre-standard C), kernighan-and-ritchie is the book (and second edition is most certainly not kr-c).

Comment: First part: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271390/whats-the-difference-between-a-cstring-a-c-string-c-strings-and-a-const Second part: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272606/merge-tags-knr-and-kr-c